# how to add an item to array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have a function that it fills the one array like below :

```
 if (isset($options[$attribute->id][$optionId])) {
                foreach ($options[$attribute->id][$optionId] as $item) {
               . . . .
                $attributeOptionsData[] = [
                    'id'           => $optionId,
                    'label'        => $attributeOption->label ? $attributeOption->label : $attributeOption->admin_name,
                    'swatch_value' => $attribute->swatch_type == 'image' ? $attributeOption->swatch_value_url : $attributeOption->swatch_value,
                    'products'     => $options[$attribute->id][$optionId],
                    'images'     => $productImage ?? null,
                ];
                dd($attributeOptionsData);
            }
```

the result of this dd is like below :

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "label" => "black"
    "swatch_value" => "#000000"
    "products" => array:1 [▶]
    "images" => "product/4618/rAkC2aC3QJB6kMiAAzIGk6nUzGHxpdfIS55g3T0P.jpeg"
  ]
]
```

now what i want to do is that after the last line add some content to this array and make it like below:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "label" => "مشکی"
    "swatch_value" => "#000000"
    "products" => array:1 [▶]
    "images" => "product/4618/rAkC2aC3QJB6kMiAAzIGk6nUzGHxpdfIS55g3T0P.jpeg"
    "custom_field" => "some value"
  ]
]
```

on the line that i dd the array i want add the customfield to it . how can i do that thanks in advance.
the reason i dont insert like others in that i want to add the  custom field in a foreach loop based on 1 field of that array

Comment: The same way you add all other fields.

Comment: What is the problem with including it in the array just like the rest of the keys?

Comment: i want to do a foreach after that and fill that inside that forach

Comment: I see no reason for another `foreach`. Can you explain why this value couldn't be computed like the others?

Comment: well the reason is in my code i need to loop though `products` and by the this whole array in generated in a foreach thats why i need to get out of that foreach fist

Comment: Iterating and building an array only to iterate the built array again to add something to it simply doesn't make sense. Is your custom field dependent only on products or something else? If you can explain on what the field depends, maybe we can suggest a more efficient way of achieving what you need.

Comment: already tryied with `array_push()`?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you simply want to add something at the bottom of an array, just use `array_push()`.
In your case, you would need to retrieve the whole `$attributeOptionsData[]` in a `foreach` loop and append the array to the key you're in, during that loop. Be aware that this is somehow inefficient. If you want to add a line based on a value you can retrieve in the first `foreach` loop, you could've just made an if-statement asking for that value and add it with `array_push()` afterwards.

Either way, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
        if (isset($options[$attribute->id][$optionId])) {
        foreach ($options[$attribute->id][$optionId] as $item) {   
            $attributeOptionsData[] = [
                'id'           => $optionId,
                'label'        => $attributeOption->label ? $attributeOption->label : $attributeOption->admin_name,
                'swatch_value' => $attribute->swatch_type == 'image' ? $attributeOption->swatch_value_url : $attributeOption->swatch_value,
                'products'     => $options[$attribute->id][$optionId],
                'images'     => $productImage ?? null,
            ];
        }

        foreach($attributeOptionsData as $key=>$data){
            array_push($attributeOptionsData[$key], ["custom_field" => "some value"])
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$attributeOptionsData` is an [associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).  You can assign values to it by specifying the array `$key`:

```
$attributeOptionsData[$key] = $value;
```